# Resizing Android partition from dual-boot Windows OS

Tags: windows, partitions

I have a Chuwi Hi8 Pro and I don't use the Windows side, so I deleted the Windows partitions to get more space following this tutorial - [Chuwi Forums - [Other] How to Delete Windows Partitions with GParted](https://web.archive.org/web/20160808201240/https://forum.chuwi.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=1880). But when I went to resize the Android data partition, it won't let me. It goes

```
/dev/mmcblk09 android_data          
/dev/mmcblk10 android_persistent    
/dev/mmcblk11 android_config         
/dev/mmcblk12 android_efi_system partition   
unallocated  17.78gb
```

I'd post a screenshot but I can't figure out how to save one to USB while in GParted.

How to give the data partition the rest of the unallocated space?

Answer (score 0):

Since it once ran Windows it must be based on Intel x86. Get a Windows again, preferrably a Windows To Go. Get [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-partition-assistant.html) Windows PE Edition. Move other partitions one by one so that the `android-userdata` partition (**not** `android_data`) is adjacent to the unallocated space. Turn to `gparted` and merge the partition with free space.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119610/discussion-on-answer-by-ibug-resizing-android-partition-from-dual-boot-windows-o).